# Setting position of ItemsControl item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol

I have a command in my viewmodel that, when executed, will add an item to an `observablecollection`. In my view, an `ItemsControl` has its source bound to this collection. So whenever an item is added, a `combobox` and a `textblock` will appear for each item.

What I'm trying to do is, have each set of combobox/textblock appear to the right of the last set, until it reaches the end of window, and then the next set will appear below the first, and so on. Was planning to put this in a `ScrollViewer`. Everything I've tried so far keeps placing each set under the last one, instead of to the right.

Here's my simple model class:

```
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double _gridColumn;
    public double GridColumn
    {
        get { return _gridColumn; }
        set { _gridColumn = value; OnPropertyChanged("GridColumn"); }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant parts of the viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int columnNum = 0;
    private ObservableCollection<DataModel> _dataModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> DataModelCollection
    {
        get { return _dataModelCollection; }
        set { _dataModelCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataModelCollection"); }
    }

    public void AddDataModel(object parameter)
    {
        DataModelCollection.Add(new DataModel {GridColumn = columnNum % 8 });
        columnNum += 2;
    }
}
```

And now my view:

```
<Grid Background="#44D3D3D3">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="46*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="139*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="38*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="78*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Content="Add Set"
            Command="{Binding AddDataModelCmd}"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="4"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="9"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="{Binding GridColumn}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="7" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="53" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
                        <TextBlock Text="tester"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I've messed around with setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate` as a `WrapPanel` which gave me the side by side result, but I couldn't get any spacing between each set of items.

Comment: use `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate` and also add `Margin` on Grid in ItemTemplate

Comment: Or use a UniformGrid as the items panel.

Comment: Both worked, thank you.